# MRAID 2 architecture and data flow

Tags: javascript, android, html, ads, mraid

I am trying to create an MRAID (v2) compliant SDK for Android, which if integrated with any android app will display rich media ads. Also, at the backend there will be a platform that will let advertisers create MRAID compliant ads/creatives, which can then be served to the SDK for display purpose. I have gone through the spec document and I am still not totally clear about the functioning and flow of the entire system as I am new to this digital ads industry.

So it will be great if someone can explain me how the entire MRAID ads works - data flow (who raises initial request for ads, how this request travels and fetches the ads, etc.) and what all components are required to create entire platform - SDK, ad creation platform etc.

Thanks!!

Comment: You might want to have a look through the MRAID documentation - it provides lots of information that might help you: http://www.iab.net/media/file/IAB_MRAID_v2_FINAL.pdf

Answer (score 1):

MRAID (v2) compliant SDK architecture contains following components

**1. Native Component :-**
Responsible for executing network calls (http ad request)
reading device information
reading GPS info
parsing ad request response
Creating html string (contains the ad data, mraid.js, bridge.js )

**2. Web View component :-** 
Webview will loads the html created by native component.

**3. Native to Java script bridge:-** 
Which will handle the communication between the ad and native components.
It will be java-script code.

Answer (score 0):

Even the thread is an old one, if some is looking for information:

MRAID is meant to allow communication between the app and the webview.
It has nothing to do with adserving and rendering ads. 
MRAID gives options to ads to be able to expand, open urls, trigger sms or tel protocolls and so on.
As already stated the given options are documented on http://www.iab.net/media/file/IAB_MRAID_v2_FINAL.pdf
There is also MRAID 3 doc on iab.net.

For adserving you will have an adserver provider and there you will get an Advertising-SDK to fetch ads. This will normally include the appside of MRAID, so you normally don't have to care.

If still you have to build the appside for MRAID, here's an example:
https://github.com/mopub/mopub-ios-sdk/tree/master/MoPubSDK/Internal/MRAID

And for WebView side:
https://gist.github.com/bensojona/1030a67464e061568a5b